# Background position does not animate in full screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-image, keyframe

Here is my CSS:

```
div.movement {
  background-image: url('image.png');
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  animation: 60s linear 0s infinite alternate moving-background;
}

@keyframes moving-background {
  to {
     background-position: 2000% 0%; 
  }
}
```

The background moves constantly when I load the webpage in regular mode. However, it stops moving as soon as I go fullscreen by pressing `F11`. I have tried both Chrome and Firefox and both behave in the same way.

Is there any way to animate a background image's position in full-screen mode? I would prefer a CSS-based solution but I am open to using JavaScript as well.

Comment: It is background-image: url('url.png') not background-image: ('url.png')

Comment: @Sanmeet Sorry, that was a typo. :)

Comment: try bacground-size:200% auto